Linear span of the amoeba of an algebraic variety
Let $X \subseteq (\mathbb{C}^\ast)^n$ be an (irreducible) algebraic variety. The amoeba of the $X$, denoted by $A(X)$, is the image of $X$ (in $ \mathbb{R}^n$) under the map ${\mathrm{Log}}(z)=(\log |z_1|, \dots, \log |z_n|)$. It seems to me that the $ \mathbb{R}$-linear span of $A(X)$ must be of the form $$\bigcap_{i=1}^k l_i^{-1}(c_i),$$ where $l_i$ are rational linear functionals. I assume that, if true, this must be well known, but I was not able to find it anywhere. I would very much appreciate a source if this (or any related) statement) is true.

I think I could sketch a convincing proof, but maybe somebody knows a reference. (My first step might be to reduce to the case in which there is no rational linear functional constant on $A(X)$.)

@TomGoodwillie I think a sketch would be very helpful.

Here is a sketch.
First reduce to the case in which there are no rational relations, as follows. Let $V$ be the vector space of all rational linear functionals that are constant on $log|A(X)|$. Choose an $n\times n$ matrix of integers, $M$, invertible over $\mathbb Q$, such that the last $d$ columns are a basis for $V$. Make a change of coordinates, writing $w_j=\prod_k z_j^{m_{k,j}}$. This turns $X$ into a variety $Y$ in which each of the coordinates $w_j$, $n-d<j\le n$, is a constant (because the logarithm of its absolute value is a constant). This $Y$ is contained in $(\mathbb C^\ast)^{n-d}\times \text{point}$, and we can now think about this subset of $(\mathbb C^\ast)^{n-d}$ instead of $X$. We are reduced to the case in which $d=0$.
So suppose that $X\subseteq (\mathbb C^\ast)^n$ has no rational relations. We have to show that it has no real relations. If $X$ is $0$-dimensional then it is a point, so $n$ must be $0$ and there are no real relations. If $X$ is positive-dimensional, then choose an algebraic curve $C$ in $X$. Without loss of generality the last coordinate $z_n$ is not constant on $C$. Consider the projection $C\to \mathbb C^\ast$ given by this coordinate. There must be a non-empty Zariski-open subset $U\subset \mathbb C^\ast$ such that the preimage in $C$ is a non-empty covering space of $U$.
Assume that there is a nontrivial relation $log |z_n|=c+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\alpha_j log|z_j|$. The real numbers $\alpha_j$ must be independent over $\mathbb Q$. Take any $p\in U$, and choose a path in $U$, starting and ending at $p$, whose winding number around $0$ is $1$. Along a lifting of that path to $C$, there is a branch of the multi-valued complex function $log(z_n^{-1}\prod_j z_j^{\alpha_j})$. This is constant, since its real part is constant. At the end of the lifted path, $z_n$ returns to its former value $p$ while any other $z_j$ gets multiplied by $e^{2\pi i\alpha_j}$. Because of the independence of the $\alpha_j$, it follows that the intersection of $X$ and $(\mathbb C^\ast)^{n-1}\times \{p\}$ is dense in $(\mathbb C^\ast)^{n-1}\times \{p\}$, for every $p\in U$. Therefore $X$ contains $(\mathbb C^\ast)^{n-1}\times U$, so that $X=(\mathbb C^\ast)^{n}$, and there are no real relations after all, a contradiction.

Thank you! I am going over the proof to digest it.
